# How to properly configured Multi-tenant in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, multi-tenant

I have created multi-tenant application, still now that working as expected.

Here is my sample code:

***middleware :***

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();


        if (! is_null($user)) {

            Config::set('database.connections.tenant.host', $user->hostname);
            Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $user->database);
            Config::set('database.connections.tenant.username', $user->username);
            Config::set('database.connections.tenant.password', $user->password);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

***database.php :***

```
'connections' => [

        'main' => [
            'driver' => env('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '123'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'tenant' => [
            'driver' => env('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql'),
            'host' => '',
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => '',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

    ],
```

**My doubt is : Above code is is possible to collapse DB connection, When multiple user access same time ? (each user has different DB)**

**for example** :user A has **school** database and user B has **college** database

user A is try to logging [loading the page] that situation user B is login.

user B has no problem but user A -- get student details from **college** database or **student** database?